Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot(1/x)$ does not exist
In Richard Hammock's Book of proof, there is an exercise asking to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\quad \text{does not exist}$$
In the answers given in the back, the argument made is $x\cot(\frac{1}{x})$ is undefined in every punctured neighbourhood of $0$ and thus the limit doesn't exist. However, this does not work if the following definition of a limit is taken

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $$x\in X,\ \  0<|x-a|<\delta \quad  \implies \quad |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$

which  deals only with the subset of the $\delta-$neighbourhood of $0$ over which $f$ is defined. A quick demsos plot, however, shows that the limit still doesn't seem to exist as the function appears to blow up in every neighbourhood of $0$. How would one go about proving inexistence using this definition?
As a supplementary question, is there any $n$ such that$\lim_{x\to 0}x^n\cot(\frac{1}{x})$ does exist?

"However, this does not work if the following definition of a limit is taken" : this is false.  It does work, under that definition of the limit.

@user2661923 would you elucidate on why that reasoning works?

To the original poster: Your comment, which I consider to be a very reasonable reaction, puts me in an awkward situation.  Opinions among MathSE reviewers are going to vary as to whether your posted question is low quality or high quality; a MathSE reviewer is not allowed to answer the posted question if they personally feel that the question is low quality.  With respect to this article on MathSE protocol, I feel that your posted question is low quality. ...see next comment

For what it's worth, if you edit your posted question to scrupulously follow the linked protocol article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response among all MathSE reviewers.

To the original poster: If you do edit your question, skipping/omitting nothing, and you are still unsatisfied with responses already given, leave me another comment, and I will provide an answer.  However, only do so after you edit the question, skipping/omitting nothing.

Actually, the proof in the book follows this definition. By taking a sequence $ x_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}, n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f(x)=x\cot (\frac{1}{x})$ is not defined at each $x_n.$
If the limit exists $(\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=A, A\in\mathbb{R})$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, such that for any $x\in (-\delta, \delta)$, we have $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon.$
But there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $|x_n-0|<\delta$, which means there always exist points $x_n$ between $(-\delta, \delta)$, so that our assumption is wrong.
For the supplementary question: no such $n$. Reason: same as above.
$\textbf{Edit}:$ Given $y_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$, we see that $f(y_n)=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$, so the only choice for $A$ is $0$. Now, by choosing $\epsilon=1$, we have $|x\cot(\frac{1}{x})|<1$ for $x\in \color{red}{(-\delta,\delta)/\{x_n\}_{n>N}}$. I want to find a contradiction by constructing another sequence $z_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{1}{n^2}}$.
$\lim\limits_{ n\to \infty} f(z_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{z_n\cos \frac{1}{z_n}}{\sin\frac{1}{z_n}}$ and the value should be $0$ if it does exist. Thus, I get $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{z_n\cos \frac{1}{z_n}}{\sin\frac{1}{z_n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{z_n}{\sin\frac{1}{z_n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2n\pi}}{\sin\frac{1}{n^2}}=0$$
Obviously wrong since $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi x}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}\to \infty\neq 0$. Also , this contradicts to $|x\cot(\frac{1}{x})|<1$.

My question was precisely about using a different definition to give the proof. You've just reporoduced a proof by the same definition as in the book

@VulgarMechanick What's the "different definition"?

I think I didn't clarify it properly. The definition in the book (which I did not bother mentioning) is different from the one I've quoted in the question – the one I want to do the proof with. Either way, your answer does not use the definition of the limit that I specified in the question.

@VulgarMechanick I think my third and fourth line follows the definition you mentioned in the question.

a point where $f$ is undefined existing in every $\delta$ neighbourhood of $a$ is NOT a contradiction as the definition explicitly requires $x$ to be in the delta neighbourhood AND in the domain of $f$.

@VulgarMechanick Edited now.

The limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} x\cot\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ exists and is igual to $L$ if, and only if, for every sequence $(x_n)$ approaching $0$, we have $\lim x_n \cot  \left(\dfrac{1}{x_n}\right) = L$.
All we have to do now is get 2 sequences approaching zero with different limits.
Take $x_n = \dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi}$, we have $x_n \cot  \left(\dfrac{1}{x_n}\right) = \dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi}\cdot \cot(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi) =0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Take $y_n = \dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi}$, we have $y_n \cot  \left(\dfrac{1}{y_n}\right) = \dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi}\cdot \cot(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi) = \dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi} \to \infty$.
The same argument applies for $x^n$.

$\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi}\to0$

$y_n=n$ works since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cot(\frac{1}{n})=\infty$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
